# Is this a crystal oscillator?

Tags: identification, oscillator, packages

I've never encountered anything in this package. Is it a crystal oscillator? What are the six pins used for? Would it potentially be ovenized?

All I know is that the manufacturer is Kyocera. Any help greatly appreciated!

Markings: Kyocera 7M37 012C M1

Logic chips, DIP-8 oscillator, and HC-49/U resonator are included for size reference. **The circular things in the middle are the mystery devices of interest.** I did not clip off two of the leads - they're all like that.
[image]

Comment: I saw relays in such packages

Comment: Is this it? (7.37MHz xtal or oscillator). No idea what the pinout is. https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/10PCS-CSTCR7M37G53-R0-CER-RESONATOR-CSTCR7M37-7M37-CSTCR7M37G-7M37G-CSTCR7M37G53-/192832390905

Comment: The 2 on the right are a crystal oscillator and a crystal. The round 6-pin packages may well be filters - possibly SAW filters (TV VSB IF or chroma filter) or a delay line from a PAL or SECAm colour TV.

Comment: If I had to guess it is a crystal oscillator complete with driver(s) on chip. I could not find data about it online but it can be ordered if they have any left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image] I have recently acquired some of these myself and was searching for info which landed me here. I was able to solve more of this mystery on my own. By orienting the tab on the can to be pin number one following the traditional DIP design.
Using pin 3 as +5V and pin 4 as the ground I was able to obtain a surprising and desirable output. Four outputs exactly. Included is my not so professional schematic . The quiescent current is a low 1.25ma so i am confident that my efforts have amounted to something. With four stable outputs at different frequency's this device truly has much potential on the bench and with a few discreet components one can produce many different wave forms. I am sure this device has more secrets as well. It took some effort but I am glad to help others and myself.

Comment: Wow, this is excellent info. Thank you for your time and effort!